# How can I iterate a String and modify some fields using java 8 feature(Stream)

Tags: regex, lambda, java-8, stream, java-stream

I want to perform multiple operation on a single String. I need to get a String and extract different sub-strings using a delimiter (";"), then again extract different sub-strings using a delimiter (":"), if the field matched then update the fields and finally join them with original state such that : ***firstName:Saroj;email:saroj@gmail.com;eaOldId;city:;center:com.test.Center::0/69***  would turn into : ***firstName:xxxxxx;email:xxxxx@xxxx.com;eaOldId;city:;center:com.test.Center::0/69***
The basic need of the problem is I need to modify some of my required fields [here 'firstName','email'] to ['xxxxxx','xxxxx@xxx.com']. I want to encrypt the sensitive data.

*I have tried the below conventional approach in a main class*

```
String shortData = "firstName:Saroj;email:saroj@gmail.com;eaOldId;city:;center:com.test.Center::0/69";
Map<String, List<String>> props = getProperties();
if(props.get("modelClasses").contains("com.test.Member")) {
   List<String> modelFields = props.get(getModelClass());
   List<String> shortDta = Stream.of(shortData.split(";")).map (elem -> new String(elem)).collect(Collectors.toList());
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(String data  : shortDta){
      String[] dta = data.split(":");
      if(dta.length>2){
          dta = data.split("=", 2);
      }
      if(dta.length == 1){
         sb.append(data).append(";");
         continue;
      }
      String key = dta[0];
      if(modelFields.stream().anyMatch(d -> d.equalsIgnoreCase(key))){
           String email = props.get("email").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
           String pattern = props.get("commonPattern").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
           sb.append(dta[0]).append(":").append(dta[0].equals("email") ? email : pattern).append(";");
      } else {
        sb.append(dta[0]).append(":;");
      }
   }
   if (sb.length() > 0) {
       sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
   }
```

*Below is the data that I'm getting from a properties file[here converting to required object manually]*

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getProperties(){
        Map<String, List<String>> props = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> str1 = new ArrayList<>();
        str1.add("firstName");
        str1.add("email");
        List<String> str2 = new ArrayList<>();
        str2.add("com.test.Member");
        str2.add("com.test.Contact");
        props.put("modelClasses", str2);
        props.put("com.test.Member", str1);
        props.put("com.test.Contact", str1);
        props.put("commonPattern", Arrays.asList("xxxxxxx"));
        props.put("email", Arrays.asList("xxxx@xxxx.com"));
        return props;
 }
```

If you notice there are multiple [ **:** ] present in the String like ***center:com.test.Center::0/69***  I need to take care this also.

Can I do the same thing using Java 8 Streams. Any help highly appreciated.Thanks!!!!!

Comment: perhaps given the standardised format, you might want to use regex instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might just use `String#replaceAll` here for a regex one line option:

```
String input = "firstName:Saroj;email:saroj@gmail.com;eaOldId;city:;center:com.test.Center::0/69";
System.out.println(input);
input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\bfirstName:)[^;]+", "xxxxxx");
input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\bemail:)[^@]+@[^;]+(\\.[^;]+)", "xxxxx@xxx$1");
System.out.println(input);
```

This prints:

```
firstName:Saroj;email:saroj@gmail.com;eaOldId;city:;center:com.test.Center::0/69
firstName:xxxxxx;email:xxxxx@xxx.com;eaOldId;city:;center:com.test.Center::0/69
```

Note: I might recommend completely making the email masked, i.e. use `xxxxx@xxx.xxx`, to avoid leaking even *any* information about the user's true email address.  By showing things like the domain and/or subdomains, you might make it easier for this information to be discovered.

Comment: :No doubt your answer & suggestion make sense, but I want dynamically data should come from a properties file(fields name, and their masked value), here I maintain two(firstName,emai) fields but actually 15-20 fields needs to mask from diff-diff Classes. Can we optimize the above code using Java 8(stream)???.Thanks.

Comment: The above code is already optimal IMHO, and I see no reason to do a split with a stream here.  The masking should _not_ at all be dynamic, but instead should be the _same_ for all users, so as to not give a potential attacker any information about these fields.